# Combine jquery on form submit with plugins for inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Im using jquery and a few input plugins like sliders checkboxes etc.
However in that form I have on form change submit (GET filtering).
Here the action will not be triggered if plugin changes the input value field.. only if the user did it.

```
$(document).on('change', '.form-onchange-submit', function (e) {
    $(this).submit();
});
```

And for example I use this code for selecting all

```
 $(document).on('click', ".select_all", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fields = $(this).data('fields');
    $("input[name='" + fields + "']").prop('checked', true);
    $("input[name='" + fields + "']").each(function () {
        var input_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('label[for="' + input_id + '"]').removeClass('selectable-deselected').addClass('selectable-selected');
    });
});
```

How do I make the form auto submit when a select_all is clicked ?

Comment: trigger it manually at end of the click function as $('.form-onchange-submit').trigger( "change" )

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would like to combine two events. you can combine multiple events with multiple selectors.

- Check event type `e.type`
- Check element id  `e.target.id`

**Example**

```
$(".select_all, #form-onchange-submit").on("click change", function(e){
    if(e.type === "change"){
         //DO STUFF UNIQUE TO CHANGE
    }
    else if(e.type === "click") {
         //DO STUFF UNIQUE TO CLICK
    }
    //DO STUFF THAT IS THE SAME
});
```

And if you would like to trigger the event manually you can use `.trigger()` as well.

```
$('#element').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     $(".select_all").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var fields = $(this).data('fields');
        $("input[name='" + fields + "']").prop('checked', true);
        $("input[name='" + fields + "']").each(function () {
            var input_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('label[for="' + input_id + '"]').removeClass('selectable-deselected').addClass('selectable-selected');
        });
     $('.form-onchange-submit').submit();
    });
```